# Create a list from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this:

```
mylist = [(20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'TBS'),...,(20, 'End', '2008-11-09', 'NG'), 
          (21, 'Start', '2008-12-10', 'TBS'),...,(21, 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'), 
          (22, 'Start', '2009-01-10', 'TBS'),...,(22, 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B'),..]
```

I put '...' in the example above to say there are other items for each id like 20, 21 and 22 in the list but I don't want them. The only items that I want are the items that include 'Start' or 'End'.(Other items have different words than these two words.)

I want to create a nested list like this:

```
[[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-11-09', 'NG'] ,
 [21, 'Start', '2008-12-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'], 
 [22, 'Start', '2009-01-10', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]
```

Here is my code:

```
code = 0
brr = []
for row in myList:
    if row[1] == "Start":
        arr = []
        code = row[0]
        arr.append([row[0], row[1], row[2]])
        continue

    if row[0] == code and row[1] == "End":
        arr.append([row[1], row[2], row[3]])
    brr.append(arr)
for k in brr:
    print(k)
```

But the problem is that it creates something like this:

```
[[[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End'], ['2008-11-09', 'NG']] ,
 [[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End'], ['2008-11-09', 'NG']] ,
 [[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End'], ['2008-11-09', 'NG']] ,
 [[21, 'Start', '2008-12-10', 'End'], ['2008-12-15', 'G']], 
 [[21, 'Start', '2008-12-10', 'End'], ['2008-12-15', 'G']],
 [[22, 'Start', '2009-01-10', 'End'], ['2009-12-10', 'B']]]
```

And for each items I have multiple rows in the list. I don't know why?
Sorry if my question is too long.

Comment: Are start and end always the first and last element of a row?

Comment: No, myList is a list of many tuples. But always start is before end. @user4343502

Comment: Within each tuple, do start and end occur once and only once each?

Comment: Also, you removed `TBS`, is that intentional?

Comment: For each tuple there is only one word. I want to say if it was start then store it to a list and then by ignoring other words I should search for end for that particular code and save it in the same list as start. @user4343502

Comment: Yes, I removed TBS intentionally. @user4343502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `brr.append(arr)` is always adding an array for each row, that's why there are 6 elements in the ouput. Change `brr.append(arr)` to:

```
if arr not in brr:
    brr.append(arr)
```

As for the format, `arr.append([row[0], row[1], row[2]])` adds a list of 3 elements, instead of 3 separate elements. Use [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) instead.

Your final code should look like this:

```
code = 0
brr = []
for row in mylist:

    if row[1] == "Start":
        arr = []
        code = row[0]
        arr.extend([row[0], row[1], row[2]])
        # continue not needed here

    if row[0] == code and row[1] == "End":
        arr.extend([row[1], row[2], row[3]])

    if arr not in brr:
        brr.append(arr)

for k in brr:
    print(k)
```

Comment: Perfect! extends works here. But I still have multiple rows for each item I don't know why. @Kacper Floriański

Comment: I literally just said that... the `brr.append(arr)` adds `arr` to `brr` each loop iteration. You have 6 tuples you iterate over so you will 6 elements in your output.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arr.extend() function

```
arr = []
arr.append([1,2]) # arr = [[1,2]]
arr = []
arr.extend([1,2])  # arr = [1,2]
```

Comment: @TemporalWolf: `arr.append` takes exactly one argument; `arr.append(1, 2)` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this pretty simply with [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) as well:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

mylist = [
    (20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'TBS'),
    (20, 'Foo', '2008-10-10', 'TBS'),
    (20, 'End', '2008-11-09', 'NG'),

    (21, 'Start', '2008-12-10', 'TBS'),
    (21, 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'),

    (22, 'Start', '2009-01-10', 'TBS'),
    (22, 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B'),
]

rows = (x for x in mylist if x[1] in ('Start', 'End'))
grouped = itertools.groupby(rows, key=lambda x: x[0])
output = [[k, *next(grp)[1:3], *next(grp)[1:4]] for k, grp in grouped]
pprint(output)
```

Output:

```
[[20, 'Start', '2008-10-10', 'End', '2008-11-09', 'NG'],
 [21, 'Start', '2008-12-10', 'End', '2008-12-15', 'G'],
 [22, 'Start', '2009-01-10', 'End', '2009-12-10', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this,

```
startlist=[]
endlist=[]
for item in mylist:
    if 'Start' in list(item):
        startlist.append(list(item))
    elif 'End' in list(item):
        endlist.append(list(item))
outlist=[i+j for i,j in zip(startlist,endlist)]
```